# Force a Soundcloud track to open in Soundcloud app on Android

Tags: android, soundcloud

I have a mobile application that links to Soundcloud track. On Android, clicking on those links brings up a dialog asking the user to "Complete action using" their browser or the Soundcloud app.

[image]

Is there a way to bypass this screen and just play the track in the Soundcloud player?

This is the code I currently using. Please suggest any modifications or new way to do this.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://m.soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/dj-nj-house-music-volume-3"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by myself. Seems like nobody knows about this.
By using the following code snippet, you can open the sound cloud player by default from your Android app.

```
String id = "114143409"; //Track id
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("soundcloud://tracks:" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

Important : You have to have install the sound cloud player on your android device.

**Update**

Soundcloud community is strictly recommending to use `sounds` instead of `tracks`

```
String id = "114143409"; //Track id
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("soundcloud://sounds:" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Scheme **soundcloud://tracks** is not working some android devices. As from soundcloud community they strictly recommend using **sounds** instead of **tracks**

```
String id = "yOUR_id"; //Track id
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("soundcloud://sounds:" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The same works with users:

```
String id = "123395690"; //Userid
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("soundcloud://users:" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```